# Azure AKS - How to give user global read permission WITHOUT Azure AD integration?

Tags: azure-aks

We have a user in our Azure AD that should have global read permission of our AKS cluster (they will be doing a security audit of the cluster). The cluster does not have "AKS-managed Azure Active Directory" enabled and I would prefer to not enable it for what is one time temporary access for a single user.

Our cluster configuration:

[image]

This is what the user is met with when attempting to view e.g. workloads in the cluster:

[image]

The only role assignment that works is "Azure Kubernetes Cluster Admin", but we want the access to be read-only. Assigning the "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader" role does not seem to have any effect.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To leverage Azure RBAC (Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Reader) you will need to integrate your [AKS with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/manage-azure-rbac#before-you-begin) .

Several other ways to authenticate against Kubernetes are described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/), but note that they are not part of Azure.

I would strongly advise to use Azure AD and Azure RBAC for your AKS.